# How to more securely store login information for my application?

Tags: django, security, passwords, password-encryption

I have a Django 1.9 application that is needs to access a few external services via SMTP and REST APIs. These all authenticate using username/password combinations that the application needs to access. For speeding up development of the rest of the system, I have just been using a file that I read in from. This is obviously not a long-term solution, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about replacing it with something more secure.

How would I go about moving from this current practice to a more secure one where my application can still access the username/password it needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to store credentials in a file on the server if the following requirements are met:

- The file isn't stored in a version control system.
- The file can be read only by the user which runs your application (you shouldn't use root for that) and a superuser.

If an intruder has access to the server and has superuser permissions, you're screwed anyway. He or she can do a memory dump and extract credentials from it.